# C++ program service

Tags: c++, windows, web-services, server

I have a personal server and I want to add some new functions to it.It is a Windows server running Windows Server 2019.The core program is wrote by me in c++,but it is just a core and can't access the Internet.It should receive a string from a webpage and return a string to it.My old way is using ASP create a file to storage the string from webpage and use my c++ program to overwrite it.But if the server get two tasks at same time,the result will become a mess.My ISP blocked port 80 so I'm using port 8012 to run my website.My router can't map to many port outside (There also a FTP service and a mail service in the server.) so I can only use the port 8012.What should I do?Should I write a C++ HTTP server?
Server Info:

Service      port-inside    port-outside      software

WEB              80             8012            IIS

FTP              21              21            Serv-U

FTP-pasv     6000-6009        6000-6009        Serv-U

POP3            110             9110

SMTP             25             9025

RemoteDesktop   3389            3389           Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my questions.I am using some AJAX code to add a time sign and random numbers to avoid request crash.
Here are the AJAX code:

```
    function GetValue(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    function SetValue(id,val)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).value=val;
        return;
    }

function GetTRValue() //Time-Random value,avoid messing up request
{
    var rdm=Math.Random().toString(16);
    var dt=new Date();
    var time=dt.getTime().toString(10);
    var tr=rdm+time;
    return tr;
}

function EncodeRequest()
{
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            SetValue('code',req.responseText);
        }
        else if(req.readyState==4 && req.status!=200)
        {
            alert('Server error:'+req.status);
        }
    }
    req.open('POST','/base/base.asp',true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.send('type=encode&code='+GetValue('base')+'&srcstr='+GetValue('str')+'&rdm='+GetTRValue());
    return;
}

function DecodeRequest()
{
    var qer=new XMLHttpRequest();
    qer.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(qer.readyState==4 && qer.status==200)
        {
            SetValue('str',qer.responseText);
        }
        else if(qer.readyState==4 && qer.status!=200)
        {
            alert('Server error:'+qer.status);
        }
    }
    qer.open('POST','/base/base.asp',true);
    qer.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    qer.send('type=decode&code='+GetValue('base')+'&srcstr='+GetValue('code')+'&rdm='+GetTRValue());
    return;
}
```

In my ASP file,I simply create a folder named the "Time-Random Value",and put request file here.Then wait for responses from C++ program,read it and delete the folder.
In my C++ program, I scan for folders and write responses into the same folder.